# using python widget classes

Tags: python, class, widget, tkinter

If this is not self-evident, I've only been coding python 2.7 tkinter for about four months.  I understand that

```
from Tkinter import* #access to libraries and widgets to write python code 
root=Tk() #creates CLI window that actually runs the module
root.mainloop() #repeats the module code ad nauseum
class = Class(root) #no clue what this actually does
```

I've written a few simple single-class modules, i.e.

```
from Tkinter import*  
class Code:     
    def __init__(self, parent):
    self.myParent = parent      
    self.main_frame = Frame(parent, background="light blue")     
    self.main_frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)  
    self.enter = Entry(self.main_frame, width=30)     
    self.enter.pack(side=LEFT, expand=NO)
root = Tk() 
code = Code(root) 
root.mainloop()
```

Now I've run across a fun little widget class on the internet--which I've stripped down to the essentials--that can make that boring entry window an autocomplete entry window, i.e.

```
import Tkinter

class AutocompleteEntry(Tkinter.Entry):

def set_completion_list(self, completion_list):
    self._completion_list = completion_list
    self._hits = []
    self._hit_index = 0
    self.position = 0
    self.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.handle_keyrelease)               

def autocomplete(self, delta=0):
    if delta:
        self.delete(self.position, Tkinter.END)
    else:
        self.position = len(self.get())
    _hits = []
    for element in self._completion_list:
        if element.startswith(self.get().lower()):
            _hits.append(element)
            if _hits != self._hits:
                    self._hit_index = 0
                    self._hits=_hits
    if _hits == self._hits and self._hits:
            self._hit_index = (self._hit_index + delta) % len(self._hits)
    if self._hits:
            self.delete(0,Tkinter.END)
            self.insert(0,self._hits[self._hit_index])
            self.select_range(self.position,Tkinter.END)

def handle_keyrelease(self, event):
    if len(event.keysym)== 1:
        self.autocomplete()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_list = ('test', 'type', 'true', 'tree')
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    entry = AutocompleteEntry(root)
    entry.set_completion_list(test_list)
    entry.pack()
    entry.focus_set()
    root.mainloop()
```

Both of these work fine solo, but I'm having several issues integrating them, not the least of which is differentiating between from Tkinter import* / root=Tk() and import Tkinter / root=Tkinter.Tk().  I thought those were just two ways of expressing the same thing?

As far as the code-class, widget-class combo is concerned, what larger framework do I need to smash these two together?  Should I make one a base class and have the other inherit?  Should I just stack them one atop the other with two roots?  Should I make them both classes under a larger super class?

UPDATED COMBINED CLASSES

```
from Tkinter import*

class AutocompleteEntry(Entry):

def set_completion_list(self, completion_list):
    self._completion_list = completion_list
    self._hits = []
    self._hit_index = 0
    self.position = 0
    self.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.handle_keyrelease)               

def autocomplete(self, delta=0):
    if delta:
        self.delete(self.position,END)
    else:
        self.position = len(self.get())
    _hits = []
    for element in self._completion_list:
        if element.startswith(self.get().lower()):
            _hits.append(element)
            if _hits != self._hits:
                    self._hit_index = 0
                    self._hits=_hits
    if _hits == self._hits and self._hits:
            self._hit_index = (self._hit_index + delta) % len(self._hits)
    if self._hits:
            self.delete(0,END)
            self.insert(0,self._hits[self._hit_index])
            self.select_range(self.position,END)

def handle_keyrelease(self, event):
    if len(event.keysym)== 1:
        self.autocomplete()

class Code:
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.myParent = parent
    self.main_frame = Frame(parent, background="light blue")
    self.main_frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    test_list = ('test', 'type', 'true', 'tree')

    self.enter = AutocompleteEntry(self.main_frame, width=30)
    self.enter.set_completion_list(test_list)
    self.enter.pack(side=LEFT, expand=NO)

root = Tk()
code = Code(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from Tkinter import *; root=Tk()` and `import Tkinter; root=Tkinter.Tk()` *are* more-or-less two ways to express the same thing. At least, both give you a root window. However, they aren't precisely equivalent. The former imports a ton of stuff into the namespace, the latter only imports one thing.

I see a lot of examples on the web that do `from Tkinter import *` but I think that is a bad idea. My preference is for `import Tkinter as tk` which (a) doesn't pollute the namespace, (b) requires minimal changes when upgrading to python 3, and (c) makes it very clear when you are calling Tkinter functions and when you are not.

As for your question about having two roots... No, don't do that. You can only have a single instance of the Tk class in an application. To use them together, either import them separately (ie: don't copy and paste them into a single file) or you will have to modify one or the other so they use the same import strategy.

Comment: When you go with import Tkinter as tk, do I change all my self.somethings to tk.somethings or does self.something still work within a class so long as I declare def __init__(self, parent)?

Comment: @Jeff: don't change your "self.somethings". What you have to change is any reference to a Tk class or value. For example, instead of `foo=Button(...)` you would do `foo=tk.Button(...)`.